# Validation in table control

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, html-table, controls

Currently I'm doing a web form and added some `textbox` for users to insert into the database. It is working alright already, the validation seems to work successfully without any exception or errors. But I need to align the `textbox` to make it properly displayed on the browser (Mozilla FireFox).

The problem is, my validation `IS IN THE TABLE` seems not to be working and I keep encountering error that stated my `textbox` is null, when I clearly filled that textbox with the correct datatype.

Here is my code:

```
<table>

  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;Customer name&nbsp;</td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomerName0" runat="server" display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="VG"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td class="style1">
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="This field must be filled in"
        ControlToValidate="txtCustomerName0"
        ValidationGroup="VG" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;Contact&nbsp;</td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtContact0" runat="server" ValidationGroup="VG"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td>
      <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator9" runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="txtContact0" ErrorMessage="Please put correct phone no."
        Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Integer"
        ValidationGroup="VG" Display="Dynamic"></asp:CompareValidator>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>ProductCode</td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtProductCode0" runat="server" ValidationGroup="VG"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>ProductName</td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtProductName0" runat="server" ValidationGroup="VG"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription0" runat="server" ValidationGroup="VG"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress0" runat="server" ValidationGroup="VG"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity0" runat="server" ValidationGroup="VG"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td>
      <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator10" runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="txtQuantity0" ErrorMessage="Please put correct quantity"
        Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Integer"
        ValidationGroup="VG"></asp:CompareValidator>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>UnitSalePrice</td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtUnitSalePrice0" runat="server" ValidationGroup="VG"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td>
      <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator11" runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="txtUnitSalePrice0" ErrorMessage="Please put correct price"
        Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Currency" 
        ValidationGroup="VG"></asp:CompareValidator>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Amount</td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount0" runat="server" ValidationGroup="VG"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td>
      <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator12" runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="txtAmount0" ErrorMessage="Please put correct amount"
        Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Currency" 
        ValidationGroup="VG"></asp:CompareValidator>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>RequiredDate</td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtRequiredDate0" runat="server" ValidationGroup="VG"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td>
      <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator13" runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="txtRequiredDate0"
        ErrorMessage="Please put correct date format" Operator="DataTypeCheck"
        Type="Date" ValidationGroup="VG"></asp:CompareValidator>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>ConfirmedDate</td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtConfirmedDate0" runat="server" ValidationGroup="VG"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td>
      <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator14" runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="txtConfirmedDate0" 
        ErrorMessage="Please put correct date format" 
        Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date" 
        ValidationGroup="VG"></asp:CompareValidator></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" onclick="btnAdd_Click" Text="ADD" ValidationGroup="VG" /></td>
    <td><asp:Button ID="btnBack0" runat="server" onclick="btnHome_Click" Text="Back" /></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Width" property for the Alignment

Comment: Where can find this "Width"? Is it in table properties?

Comment: Look at the properties of the Controls.

Comment: I tried but nothing happen. Actually, can U be more precise on this? I'm quit lost here. If there anything to amend in table cotrol here, can U send me the codes? Stuck with head bang here:(

Answer (score 0):

Make css file for that. In the file add one class, for example:

```
.textbox
{
text-align:center;  
}
```

apply that `cssclass="textbox"` with you `textbox` and
you will get textbox align.

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtConfirmedDate0" runat="server" cssclass="textbox" ValidationGroup="VG">